# Comparing different small sample sizes

Tags: neural-networks, small-sample

I sadly don´t know alot about statistics that´s why I hope you could help me.  I´m currently comparing two different configurations of a neural network.  My datapoints are the standard deviations of the Neuron activities in the hidden layer after a particular set of inputs. Configuration A has only 3 neurons in the hidden layer and Configuration B has 25 neurons in the hidden layer.  So the sample sizes I want to compare would be $n = 3$ vs $n = 25$.  The assumption is that the standard deviations, of the activities in the hidden neurons, in configuration B are significantly higher than in configuration A (so I want to compare the means of my two datasets...I guess).

Due to $n = 3$ beeing so small I thought about repeating the experiment multiple times and just put the data together into one category n_(experiment 1 config A + experiment 2 config A + experiment 3 config A) = 9 vs   n_(experiment 1 config B + experiment 2 config B + experiment 3 config B) = 75.  Is that a problem?

After that I would check if the datasets are normal distributed and chose either the t-test or the Man-Whitney-U test. 
But my datasets are also quiet different in size. If anyone has an idea how to get a valid result I´d be grateful ( I really should have taken a statistics course at some point :s )